# UWP Content Dialog and Content Frame

Tags: c#, uwp, frame

I am having a little problems with my frame.

I write a static method, it draws a content dialog with a textbox inside, if the textbox isn't empty, it should open the `page_2`.

> Currently I am using `"ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page_2), "operation");"` ,
>
> But my project have a pane Hamburguer menu on mainpage and it should be on all the pages.
>   and if I use ContentFrame.Navigate it disappears.

Here are my static content dialog:

```
    public static async void D_NewProject(double Widthmax)
    {
        ContentDialog D_NewProject = new ContentDialog()
        {
            Title = "New Project",
            MaxWidth = Widthmax, // this.ActualWidth,
        };

        StackPanel D_panel = new StackPanel();


        TextBox TextBox_D1 = new TextBox()
        {
            PlaceholderText = "Name:",
            TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
        };

        D_panel.Children.Add(TextBox_D1);

        D_NewProject.Content = D_panel;


        D_NewProject.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";
        D_NewProject.PrimaryButtonClick += delegate
        {
            if (TextBox_D1.Text != "")
            {
            /**/
                Frame ContentFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
                ContentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page_2), "operation");
            /**/
            }
        };
        await D_NewProject.ShowAsync();
    }
```

If you need more code like the pane, you can ask for it.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a layout page that would be active in all page,
you need to make a method in `App.xaml.cs` which loads the current page inside of this layout.
I can suggest you this method that I use it myself:

```
public static void LoadLayout(Type pageType)
{
    // just ensure that the window is active
    RootFrame = new _Layout();
    RootFrame.ContentFrame.Navigate(pageType, null);
    RootFrame.ContentFrame.Navigated += ContentFrame_Navigated;
    ContentFrame_Navigated(null, null);
    Window.Current.Content = RootFrame;
}
```

The `ContentFrame_Navigated` delegate is used just for controlling the items on the layout (for example: Buttons, ...).

Comment: I am having some problems implementing your solution: "The type or namespace name "_Layout" could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)" .

Comment: @Julius `_Layout ` is the page that you want to use in all of the pages, I named it: `_Layout`.